# Making text go on the odd page in a book class

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

In the book class, how do I make sure a particular text I type goes on the odd page? Is there a command to "flush" the current page *only* if it happens to currently be an even page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your own command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand\alwaysodd[1]{%
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
#1%
\else
\mbox{}\clearpage#1%
\fi
}

\begin{document}
text \alwaysodd{test}
\newpage
text \alwaysodd{test}
\end{document}
```

A variant without arguments:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand\alwaysodd{%
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage\else
\mbox{}\clearpage%
\fi
}

\begin{document}
text \alwaysodd test
\newpage
text \alwaysodd test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't this be simplified into a command with no arguments? So just typing `\alwaysodd` would do the trick. Then I don't have to make the command surround anything particular.

Comment: @MayGodBlessKnuth of course (I thought you required the argument); see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Of course you're right -- I've deleted my non-answer